# How do I select a specific custom view in a google sheet using code

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with a column that is used to discriminate across various centers. Each row identifies the appropriate one by its email address.
I am creating as many subviews as there are email addresses and would like to:

1. Enumerate them
2. Switch to each one of those sub-views

Do you know if it's possible to do and, if so, how? My google-fu seems lacking.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it depend of what you expect as output, does the output need to be editable or does it only need to be viewable. In the hypothesis of the second option you could use a formula "filter" instead of the "filtered views" the formula filter can be based on on specific cell where you put a drop down of all your options. [eg here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19lPE9fjNY-5B6V1fpc9eq_XQtNNKuqG4hPMCE6LZndg/edit#gid=2057311785)